# VS code shows incorrect syntax errors in correct sql

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code

I have `init.sql` file that starts with

```
\connect postgres
```

since I want the SQL provided to be executed in `postgres` db.

VS code seems not aware that this is correct and shows 3 errors:

- `Incorrect syntax near '\'`
- `'connect' is not a recognised option`
- `Incorrect syntax near 'postgres'`

how to make it recognise this as correct?

Comment: `\connect` is a meta command  that is only valid in the `psql` client. If you are trying to run it as SQL then you will the syntax error.

Comment: Hi. VS code is actually providing a correct error. \c and \connect are PSQL commands, which is a Postgresql CLI utility. \connect is not a valid/correct SQL statement. You should check if there is PSQL based plugin for VS Code, which will be able to also interpret PSQL commands as valid.

Comment: All valid **SQL** commands are [listed in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) - `\connect` is not one of them.

Comment: Slight correction: \connect is in deed not a SQL command. It is a psql meta-command https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing file extention from `.sql` to `.psql` did the trick for me.